# Warn when casting to a smaller type in a function call?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I had the following problem:

```cs
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
int someVar = ...;
indices.Add((ushort)someVar);
```

which resulted in `indices` to never exceed 65535 and it messed up our 3D Mesh rendering.
It probably happened when upgrading from `ushort` to `int` in the List, but the insertion in the list was untouched during refactors.

Is there a warning that could be enabled? Since `List<int>.Add()` would expect an `int` anyway.
There is [IDE0004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0004) but in our case it was not triggered.

Comment: Have you considered compiling in `checked` mode? That'll probably give you a runtime `OverflowException`, at least making it obvious

Comment: What type is `someVar`? You would only get a warning about an unnecessary cast if it was `ushort` already`.  If it's not `object` containing a boxed `ushort` value, one has to wonder why you're casting as that type in the first place. You're not going to get a warning when assigning a `ushort` where an `int` is expected because it's a widening conversion, i.e. no data can possibly be lost. Your issue is not adding the value to the list but truncating the value earlier.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `someVar` is of type `int`

Comment: @MarcGravell Turning on the Checked environment makes it throw an exception. But having a warning at compilation would be better

Comment: Using an explicit cast is telling the compiler, "I know what I'm doing." From [the M/S docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions): *A cast is a way of explicitly informing the compiler that you intend to make the conversion and that you are aware that data loss might occur, or the cast may fail at run time.*

Comment: The explicit cast is meaningful because it takes an expression of type `int` and performs a narrowing conversion to `ushort`. That resulting `ushort` can be used where ever an `int` is expected because the inverse conversion is widening and thus is defined as implicit.